# How to tidy up node arrangement in Shader editor

Tags: node-editor, shader-nodes

I'm working on a blender project where all the nodes in the Shader window are on top of each other.  For every material, I need to go through and move them around to make all the nodes visible.  Is there a quick way to tidy these up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Node Arrange](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/node/node_arrange.html) add-on does this, and it comes with Blender by default. Enable it and you'll see it show up in the Properties sidebar

Comment: If this answer helped, please mark it as the correct answer for when people find this question in the future

Comment: thanks very much - the system wouldn't let me mark it as answered yesterday - (it kept asking me to wait)